# при шаринге в whatsapp переход на следующую строку не работает "\n"

Tags: ios, swift

Задача стоит сделать шаринг текста. Проблема в том что у меня должен быть переход на новую строку. Я сделал это с помощью "\n". Это работает для VK, Сообщений, Telegram и тд, но для WhatsApp это не работает, кто может сталкивался с подобным просьба помочь.

Пытался заюзать этот [вариант](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34695055/new-line-in-whatsapp-vs-mail), не получилось.

Вот мой код :

```
// нажатие на кнопку шаринга.
func actionShare(){
    let textToShare = getArrayShare()
    let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: textToShare, applicationActivities: nil)
    activityViewController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view // so that iPads won't crash
    activityViewController.excludedActivityTypes = [ UIActivityType.airDrop]
    /*
    activityViewController.completionWithItemsHandler = {(activityType) in
        if activityType.0!.rawValue == "net.whatsapp.WhatsApp.ShareExtension" {
            print("whats app")
        }
    }
    */
    self.present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func getArrayShare() -> [String] {                
    let text = NSLocalizedString("signUpPage.SendMobileApp", comment: "Отправлено из мобильного приложения")

    // text to share
    let text1 = "first text"//"\(newsAboutOne[0].title)"
    let url = "\nsecond text url"//"\n\(newsAboutOne[0].url)"
    let text3 = "\n\n\(text) My App" //заглушка

    let textToShare = [ text1, url, text3 ]
    return textToShare
}
```

Вот скрин шаринг в сообщениях :

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот скрин шаринг в WhatsApp :

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Вроде как с 2017-07-19 должно работать нормально и с **\n**, раньше нужно было подменять **\n** на < br>. Пример:

```
string.replacingOccurrences(of:"\n", with:"<br>")
```